# Which type in entities for PostGIS/Hibernate Spatial

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial

I already manage to store, read and update PostGIS rows with Hibernate Spatial with a Point and a MLineString in a very simple case : a MLineString defining a road, display a point along this road function on the time (the M dimension).

However, I'm still confused about which type to use.

There is the model packages from PostgreSQL driver, PostGIS plugin (PGxx), Hibernate, HibernateSpatial, JTS ... What type set from which library should I use in my entities.